# Changing datatype in GDAL (python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, gdal, rasterizing, uint

I wrote a script to rasterize different vector files the one after the other, during this process you have to input the cost per pixel for that specific layer. Eventually I am trying to achieve one raster file containing all the initial vector files which are now all represented by a different cost in a single raster file.

Now the problem is that when my inputted cost exceeds 255, that the cost in the raster file will just be 255. This is probably because of gdal using the Byte data-type. I tried to change it to GDAL_UInt16 to gat values up to 65535 but this is not working... When I output a file with the code below, I'll still get a file with values that range between 0 and 255.

Can anybody help me?

```
   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from osgeo import gdal, ogr, osr
import os

RASTERIZE_COST_FIELD = "__pixelkost__"
xmi = 0
xma = 0
ymi = 0
yma = 0


def rasterize(pixel_size=1):

    # Ask for systempath towards main file
    print ""
    print "**************************************************"
    print "**                                              **"
    print "**  Please enter the systempath towards the     **"
    print "**  shapefile which ranges over the total sur-  **"
    print "**  face area of the used region. This will     **"
    print "**  probably be the file with administrative    **"
    print "**  lots.                                       **"
    print "**                                              **"
    print "**************************************************"
    print ""

    path = one()

    # Ask for cost

    cost1 = three()

    # produce the outputpath
    (shapefilefilepath, shapefilename) = os.path.split(path)
    (shapefileshortname, extension) = os.path.splitext(shapefilename) 

    ofp = shapefilefilepath + "/" + shapefileshortname + ".img"

    # Open the data source
    orig_data_source = ogr.Open(path)

    # Make a copy of the layer's data source because we'll need to 
    # modify its attributes table
    source_ds = ogr.GetDriverByName("Memory").CopyDataSource(
            orig_data_source, "")
    source_layer = source_ds.GetLayer(0)
    source_srs = source_layer.GetSpatialRef()
    x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max = source_layer.GetExtent()
    xmi = x_min
    ymi = y_min
    xma = x_max
    yma = y_max

    # Create a field in the source layer to hold the features pixelkost
    field_def = ogr.FieldDefn(RASTERIZE_COST_FIELD, ogr.OFTReal)
    source_layer.CreateField(field_def)
    source_layer_def = source_layer.GetLayerDefn()
    field_index = source_layer_def.GetFieldIndex(RASTERIZE_COST_FIELD)

    # Generate random values for the field (it's here that the value
    # of the attribute should be used, but you get the idea)
    for feature in source_layer:
        feature.SetField(field_index, cost1) 
        source_layer.SetFeature(feature)

    # Create the destination data source
    x_res = int((x_max - x_min) / pixel_size)
    y_res = int((y_max - y_min) / pixel_size)
    target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(ofp, x_res,
            y_res, 1, gdal.GDT_UInt16)
    target_ds.SetGeoTransform((
            x_min, pixel_size, 0,
            y_max, 0, -pixel_size,
        ))
    if source_srs:
        # Make the target raster have the same projection as the source
        target_ds.SetProjection(source_srs.ExportToWkt())
    else:
        # Source has no projection (needs GDAL >= 1.7.0 to work)
        target_ds.SetProjection(ofp)
    # Rasterize
    err = gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], source_layer,
            burn_values=[2509],
            options=["ATTRIBUTE=%s" % RASTERIZE_COST_FIELD])

    target_ds = None

    Array1 = raster2array(ofp)
    a = 1

    print ""
    print "**************************************************"
    print "**                                              **"
    print "**  Please enter, one by one, the systempath    **"
    print "**  towards the shapefile you want to add to    **"
    print "**  the set of rasterfiles. These will be       **"
    print "**  merged to one final cost-file.              **"
    print "**                                              **"
    print "**  If you want to stop adding shapefiles, type **"
    print "**                  STOP                        **"
    print "**                                              **"
    print "**************************************************"
    print ""

    while a != "STOP":
        # Ask for systempath towards next file
        path2 = one()

        # Ask for cost
        cost2 = three()

        print ""
        print "This process may take a while, please be patient."

        # produce the outputpath
        (shapefilefilepath, shapefilename) = os.path.split(path2)
        (shapefileshortname, extension) = os.path.splitext(shapefilename) 

        ofp2 = shapefilefilepath + "/" + shapefileshortname + ".img"


        # Open the data source
        orig_data_source = ogr.Open(path2)

        # Make a copy of the layer's data source because we'll need to 
        # modify its attributes table
        source_ds = ogr.GetDriverByName("Memory").CopyDataSource(
                orig_data_source, "")
        source_layer = source_ds.GetLayer(0)
        source_srs = source_layer.GetSpatialRef()

        # Create a field in the source layer to hold the features pixelkost
        field_def = ogr.FieldDefn(RASTERIZE_COST_FIELD, ogr.OFTReal)
        source_layer.CreateField(field_def)
        source_layer_def = source_layer.GetLayerDefn()
        field_index = source_layer_def.GetFieldIndex(RASTERIZE_COST_FIELD)
        for feature in source_layer:
            feature.SetField(field_index, cost2)
            source_layer.SetFeature(feature)
        x_res = int((x_max - x_min) / pixel_size)
        y_res = int((y_max - y_min) / pixel_size)
        target_ds = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(ofp2, x_res,
                y_res, 1, gdal.GDT_UInt16)
        target_ds.SetGeoTransform((
                x_min, pixel_size, 0,
                y_max, 0, -pixel_size,
            ))
        if source_srs:
            target_ds.SetProjection(source_srs.ExportToWkt())
        else:
            target_ds.SetProjection(ofp2)
        err = gdal.RasterizeLayer(target_ds, [1], source_layer,
                burn_values=[2509],
                options=["ATTRIBUTE=%s" % RASTERIZE_COST_FIELD])

        target_ds = None

        Array2 = raster2array(ofp2)

        length = len(Array1)
        length2 = len(Array1[1])

        l = 0

        while l < length:
            l2 = 0
            while l2 < length2:
                Array1[l,l2] += Array2[l,l2]
                l2 += 1
            l2 = 0
            l += 1

        while True:
            try:
                a = str(input("Press enter if you want to continue inputting shapefiles. Otherwise type STOP: "))
                break
            except (NameError, SyntaxError, ValueError, TypeError):
                print ""
                print("This is not a string. Please do not forget to type your input between quotation marks.")
                print ""
            except (UnicodeEncodeError):
                print("Please do not use special characters in the systempath.")
                print ""

    return (Array1, path, ofp)

def one():
    while True:
        try:
            syspath = str(input("Systempath: "))
            break
        except (NameError, SyntaxError, ValueError, TypeError):
            print ""
            print("This is not a string. Please do not forget to type your input between quotation marks.")
            print ""
        except (UnicodeEncodeError):
            print("Please do not use special characters in the systempath.")
            print ""
    return syspath

def three():
    while True:
        try:
            cost = int(input("Cost per squared meter for this type of land-use: "))
            break
        except (NameError, ValueError, SyntaxError, UnicodeEncodeError):
            print ""
            print("This is not a numerical value, please re-enter.")
            print ""
    return cost

def raster2array(rasterfn):
    raster = gdal.Open(rasterfn)
    band = raster.GetRasterBand(1)
    array = band.ReadAsArray()
    return array

def array2raster(newRasterfn,rasterfn,array):
    raster = gdal.Open(rasterfn)
    geotransform = raster.GetGeoTransform()
    originX = geotransform[0] # East/West location of Upper Left corner
    originY = geotransform[3] # North/South location of Upper Left corner
    pixelWidth = geotransform[1] # X pixel size
    pixelHeight = geotransform[5] # Y pixel size
    cols = array.shape[1]
    rows = array.shape[0]

    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
    outRaster = driver.Create(newRasterfn, cols, rows, gdal.GDT_UInt16)
    outRaster.SetGeoTransform((originX, pixelWidth, 0, originY, 0, pixelHeight))
    outband = outRaster.GetRasterBand(1)
    outband.WriteArray(array)
    outRasterSRS = osr.SpatialReference()
    outRasterSRS.ImportFromWkt(raster.GetProjectionRef())
    outRaster.SetProjection(outRasterSRS.ExportToWkt())
    outband.FlushCache() 



if __name__ == '__main__':
    A1, pa, imgpa = rasterize()

    (shapefilefilepath, shapefilename) = os.path.split(pa)
    ofp3 = shapefilefilepath + "/merge.img"

    array2raster(ofp3,imgpa,A1)

    print ""
    print "**************************************************"
    print ""
    print "The merged rasterfile has been saved at:"
    print ""
    print str(ofp3)
    print ""
    print "**************************************************"
```

Comment: Can you check with a gdalinfo command whether the output raster data type is uint16? I think that should be fine. The issue here could be that when you do `Array1 = raster2array(ofp)` you load the band with `band.ReadAsArray()` which will create an array of the same type as the input raster (byte). You can check what's the type of `Array1` with this instruction: `print Array1.dtype`. To generate an array where you can store bigger numbers you can replace `array = band.ReadAsArray()` with `array = band.ReadAsArray().astype(numpy.int16)` (you may need a `import numpy`).

Comment: It didn't help.. Both types are int16 but I am still getting max values 255. I was thinking it might be a problem with the following code: `    field_def = ogr.FieldDefn(RASTERIZE_COST_FIELD, ogr.OFTReal)
    source_layer.CreateField(field_def)
    source_layer_def = source_layer.GetLayerDefn()
    field_index = source_layer_def.GetFieldIndex(RASTERIZE_COST_FIELD)`A new layer/ field is created but it is not defined as int16.. Could this be the problem? How can I change the type to int16? I tried field_def.SetType(self, numpy.int16) but I get an error that it doesn't know 'self'

Comment: Hi I think that you do not need to pass self there, just `field_def.SetType(numpy.int16) ` should work.